# Correct usage of pronoun in the following sentence

Tags: word-choice, pronouns, relative-pronouns

> 1) Every student was selected for **their/his** placement training in the
>   college.
>
> 2) Each girl was given a bunch of flowers which pleased **her/them** very much.

Could anyone clear my doubt which pronoun to be used here.

Answer (score 1):

In both of your examples, according to technical English, the singular form should be used; however, in spoken English, either way is considered to be acceptable.  In fact, using their/them may be more common than using the singular forms.

Comment: Formally and grammatically which one is more apt?

Comment: Formally, the first sentence should use *his*. The second sentence, IMO, either would be correct. Using *her* emphasizes that every individual girl was very pleased, while using *them* emphasizes that they were all very pleased. Essentially the same meaning.

Comment: In the first sentence, each student's possessive can be his/her because we do not know each student's gender. We tend to replace 'his/her' with 'they' to make it simple. 'they' in such a case is often referred to as 'Singular they'.

Comment: As we all know, there's no definitive "authority" who can say what's "technically correct", but I can't really agree with your assertion there. Consider, for example (http://grammar.about.com/od/rs/g/Singular-They.htm)[Though strict prescriptive grammarians regard the singular they as a grammatical error, it has been in widespread use for several centuries. Singular they appears in the writings of Chaucer, Shakespeare, Austen, Woolf, and many other major English authors]. If it's good enough for them, I don't think we should be saying it's not strictly "correct".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Were Chaucer, Shakespeare, etc. going for perfect grammar or for effective story telling?

Comment: Does it really make any difference? They are some of our *great* writers, who effectively *define* "good practice". If you think grammar means a set of prescriptive rules, that's your prerogative, but I'd rather see it as a description of what competent speakers say/write.